# How do I see my Heroic dungeon locks for much lower level dungeons?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I ran a BurningCrusade Heroic 5 man yesterday and went back today to find that I'm still locked (no bosses were spawned).  I can see Cataclysm Heroic dungeon locks through the RandomDungeonFinder, but I can't see my BurningCrusade Heroic lock there.

Where can I see whether I'm locked to a BurningCrusade Heroic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press O, then go to the raid tab - there is a button Raid Info. There should be all instances/raids you are locked in. [image]