# Is there a reset time limit for Obsidian and Ruby Sanctum?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am new to WoW and have entered and completed the Ruby Sanctum and the Obsidian Sanctum once each. I am trying to do the instances again and they won't reset.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/82404/9192

Answer (score 5):

Both of these instances are raid instances. As such you can only complete them once a week. They will reset during server maintenance which will usually occur on a Tuesday.

Edit: Thanks Michael Hampton
Resets are now at the same time for all servers in a region, Tuesday 15:00 UTC for NA realms, and Wednesday 07:00 UTC for EU realms.

Comment: Resets are now at the same time for all servers in a region, [Tuesday 15:00 UTC](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/20745655899) for NA realms, and [Wednesday 07:00 UTC](http://eu.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/17612252415) for EU realms.

Comment: You can also see this ingame. All your active locks (including non-raid) are under Social -> Raid -> Raid info